# measuring time between two rising edges in beaglebone

Tags: interrupt, frequency, beagleboneblack

I am reading sensor output as square wave(0-5 volt) via oscilloscope. Now I want to measure frequency of one period with **Beaglebone**. So I should measure the time between two **rising edge**s. However, I don't have any experience with working Beaglebone. Can you give some advices or sample codes about measuring time between rising edges?

Answer (score 0):

How deterministic do you need this to be?  If you can tolerate some inaccuracy, you can probably do it on the main Linux OS; if you want to be fancy pants, this seems like a potential use case for the BBB's PRU's (which I unfortunately haven't used so take this with substantial amounts of salt).  I would expect you'd be able to write PRU code that just sits with an infinite outerloop and then inside that loop, start looping until it sees the pin shows 0, then starts looping until the pin shows 1 (this is the first rising edge), then starts counting until either the pin shows 0 again (this would then be the falling edge) or another loop to the next rising edge... either way, you could take the counter value and you should be able to directly convert that into time (the PRU is states as having fixed frequency for each instruction, and is a 200Mhz (50ns/instruction).  Assuming your loop is something like

```
#starting with pin low
inner loop 1:
registerX = loadPin
increment counter
jump if zero registerX to inner loop 1
# pin is now high
inner loop 2:
registerX = loadPin
increment counter
jump if one registerX to inner loop 2
# pin is now low again
```

That should take 3 instructions per counter increment, so you can get the time as 3 * counter * 50 ns.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Foon in his answer, the PRUs are a good fit for this task (although depending on your requirements it may be fine to use the ARM processor and standard GPIO). Please note that (as far as I know) both the regular GPIOs and the PRU inputs are based on 3.3V logic, and connecting a 5V signal might fry your board! You will need an additional component or circuit to convert from 5V to 3.3V.

I've written a [basic example](https://github.com/sv3/freq) that measures timing between rising edges on the header pin P8.15 for my own purpose of measuring an engine's rpm. If you decide to use it, you should check the timing results against a known reference. It's *about* right but I haven't checked it carefully at all. It is implemented using PRU assembly and uses the [pypruss](https://bitbucket.org/intelligentagent/pypruss) python module to simplify interfacing.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. You can find more information at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).